# Why the ContourPlot and ListContourPlot show reversed plot?

Tags: plotting

dear All! Here are my code for the same kind of plot, because I thought Contour Plot is time-consuming, so I tried ListContourPlot instead. But I don't understand why the figure generated by ListContourPlot seems to have flipped axis?

Code using test function:

```
F[x_, c_] := 1 - CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1 - x] - c]

maxp[a_, b_, c_, alpha_] := F[alpha, (10* a)/Sqrt[1 - a^2]] * F[alpha, (10 * b *Sqrt[(1 - a^2)])/Sqrt[1 - c^2 - b^2 - 2*a*b*c]]

ListContourPlot[Table[maxp[a, b, 0, 0.05], {a, 0, 0.96, 0.02}, {b, 0, 0.96, 0.02}] ,
ColorFunction -> (ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"]),  FrameLabel -> {a, b}, 
PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"BlueGreenYellow", {0, 1}}], 
Contours -> {0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9}, 
DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]

ContourPlot[maxp[a, b, 0, 0.05], {a, 0, 0.96}, {b, 0, 0.96}, 
ColorFunction -> (ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"]),  FrameLabel -> {a, b}, 
PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"BlueGreenYellow", {0, 1}}], 
Contours -> {0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9}]
```

And the figure generated by ListContourPlot: [image]

the figure generated by ContourPlot: [image]

Looks like two figures are flipped. Why does that happen?

Comment: It is iteration inside `Table` that flipped the data. Swap iterators `a` and `b` like `Table[maxp[a, b, 0, 0.05], {b, 0, 0.96, 0.02}, {a, 0, 0.96, 0.02}]` and the plots will be the same.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense now.

Answer (score 4):

For `ListContourPlot`,we need to use `Transpose` the data.

```
ListContourPlot[
 Transpose@
  Table[maxp[a, b, 0, 0.05], {a, 0, 0.96, 0.02}, {b, 0, 0.96, 0.02}], 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"]), 
 FrameLabel -> {a, b}, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"BlueGreenYellow", {0, 1}}], 
 Contours -> {0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9}, 
 DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Not a good way of doing it, especially for big data. No need to transpose anything if you construct the table the right way in the first place.